# get values from a taylor.diagram in R

Tags: r

I am using **taylor.diagram** in R to evaluate the model performance. The below codes can make a sample taylor.diagram plot:

```
library(plotrix)

# create random data as the reference data
ref <-rnorm(30,sd=2)

# create some data as the model results
model <- ref+rnorm(30)

# display the diagram to evaluate the model peformance
plot <-taylor.diagram(ref,model)
```

Now my question is: how can I extract data results from this diagram? I need standard deviations (ref and model), correlation coefficient (r value), and centered root-mean-square (RMS).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor diagram is a visualization tool and although it calculates this metrics you cannot access them. You can calculate them using R.

```
Metrics::rmse(ref,model)
stats::cor(ref,model, method= c('pearson))
sd(ref)
```